# TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessions' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, testng, supertest

I am writing tests and I do not know js well, but I need to find the answer quickly. In the courses, I have not reached this point yet, or maybe I just don’t understand. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have two questions:

- The test starts working as soon as I delete the line:

  ```
  .then((response) => {
     authId = response.body.result.sessions[0].authId;
  });
  ```

if you do not delete this line, an error appears:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'sessions' of undefined`

- How to write so that the fields are optional, that is, you can pass, or you can not pass

`(props: { authId: string; deviceId: string })`

This is the response.body I am trying to parse:

```
{
  "result": {
    "sessions": [
      {
        "type": "web",
        "authId": "jRXtO7oNiBR5Ldeq",
        "platform": "platform",
        "application": "application",
        "seenAt": 1592052380
      }
    ],
    "integrations": []
  },
  "success": true
}
```

My code:

```
import { agent } from 'supertest';
import { config } from '../../config';
import { getSsoId } from '../../helpers/getUserFromGenesis';

describe('First', () => {
    let id;
    let authId;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        id = await getId();
    });

    const userAuthorizations = (fn: (response: any) => void) =>
        agent(config.baseUrl)
            .get(`users/${id}/authorizations?client_id=test`)
            .auth(config.user, config.pass)
            .expect((response) => {
                fn(response);
            });

    const deleteUserAuthorizations = (props: { authId: string; deviceId: string }) =>
        agent(config.baseUrl)
            .delete(`users/authorizations`)
            .auth(config.user, config.pass)
            .send(props)
            .expect((response) => {
                expect(response.body.result.success).toEqual(true);
            });

    const getSession = () =>
        agent(config.tokenQaUrl)
            .post(`/token`)
            .auth(config.user, config.pass)
            .send({
                clientId: 'test',
                userId: id,
            })
            .expect((response) => {
                expect(response.body.sessionId).not.toEqual('');
                expect(response.body.sessionId).not.toEqual(null);
            })
            .then((response) => {
                authId = response.body.result.sessions[0].authId;
            });

    it('test', async () => {
        await getSession().then(() =>
            userAuthorizations((response) => {
                expect(response.body.result.sessions.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
            }),
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: ```fields are optional``` means you have to make these field optional 
```props: { authId: string; deviceId: string }```

Comment: That is, in this form are they optional?

Comment: no they are not optional but if you want to make them optional then try adding ```?``` in front of them for example
```props: { authId?: string; deviceId?: string }```

Comment: with respect to your first question first check what is present in the request.body before trying to access the session

Comment: Yes, I apologize, did not add. 
This is the response.body I am trying to parse:
`{
  "result": {
    "sessions": [
      {
        "type": "web",
        "authId": "jRXtO7oNiBR5Ldeq_token_service",
        "platform": "platform",
        "application": "application",
        "seenAt": 1592052380
      }
    ],
    "integrations": []
  },
  "success": true
}`

Comment: do your second question is answered ?, and about the JSON you provided is working with the way you are accessing it, I think so that issue is that your response is not getting the value in which you want

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got the answer to the second question!

Comment: you can check my answer, you can mark it as accepted as 2nd question is done will help others also

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comment

1. It seems like some time your response is getting the JSON data in the way which you are trying to access, but some time its not. Its better to add conditions before trying to access data where the JSON is not of fixed structure.
2. To make these property optional just add `?`
   it will make the properties option
   `props: { authId?: string; deviceId?: string }`

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unclear on your question.  There are some good answers up top.

In case you  are trying to avoid a "property of undefined error" you can do something like this:

```
authId = response?.body?.result?.sessions[0]?.authId;
```

it prevents the error. Ideally you would type-check all of them.